# how to open existing instance of opera in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup on a site that assigns a unique identifier to the session when a user logs in (e.g. `d83c231c-a1a0-4b9b-85bb-7cc36aa6b66c`) as well as a "serial number": `serial:"ABzepITkLfRuQ+4hCMTXfA`.

Upon examination via WebDriver, it seems that I receive a newly generated guid and serial number every time I login to the site if i use WebDriver. Is there a way to open the same instance of a browser programmatically so that it appears as the same guid to the site each time?

This is what i am using now to open browser:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pprint

webdriver_service = service.Service('operadriver')
webdriver_service.start()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe"
driver = webdriver.Opera(opera_options=options) # success!

driver.get('http://somesite.com')
```

Comment: How can you be sure that the guid that's being generated is purely a function of the user agent?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you, every time i open a browser using selenium, i get different ID, i just want to get them same as my browser when i click on it. I am not sure how the site generate this ID but it's just different if i use selenium to open browser, if i run browser manually i always get the same ID as long as i don't reinstall system, but in few cases i get different ID when deleted cookies

Comment: Are you using Selenium to open an instance of Opera, visit a website, and login (successfully) to that website? After establishing a session, you see values in a cookie associated with two keys called `serial` and `id`, respectively--is that what you're describing?

Comment: when i type username and pass and when i click sign in, it send user and pass with device guid to the server in request payload, then if i have already that guid in my account or if i have a free slot i can log in. In short i get uuid before i login to site, now it seems that serial is not important, i think that's just something they use to make uuid